# Rust in-place modify withg FFI

Tags: opencv, rust

We're trying to use rust with the `opencv` crate, which provides thin bindings over the c++ api. In the c++ api, various functions, including e.g. `imgproc::blur` take a source pointer and a destination pointer. If you want to modify in place, you just pass a single pointer to source and dest.

In rust, this means that the api for these functions take an `&dyn ToInputArray` and an `&dyn mut ToInputArray`. The problem is, then you can't modify in place, because `imgproc::blur(&newFrame, &mut newFrame, ...);` is taking a mutable and immutable borrow at the same time. One solution I can see to this is to do a double buffer set up, but that seems less efficient than just writing in place. Is there a safe solution to my problem? If not, an unsafe solution?

Comment: I don't know OpenCV so I will not write an answer, but you can use raw pointers with the API directly (basically bypass the wrapper crate).

Comment: **pointers**? OpenCV doesn't take pointers. it takes `cv::Mat` instances. -- perhaps model that as having a function `blurInplace` to cover the situation, or perhaps the rust equivalent is to have two overloads of the same function, one with and one without mutable src?

Comment: I would be very surprised if providing the same pointer (or whatever) for source and destination actually performed the operation correctly. If the two pointers are distinct, then placing computed values in the destination does not alter the source and does not require an intermediate storage. On the other hand, with the same pointer, as soon as a destination value is stored, it alters the original source in a way that can affect the neighbouring pixels (except if an intermediate storage is silently allocated). Rust memory safety is useful ;^)

Comment: so these comments are right it turns out

in place modification is bad and leads to subtly bad results, which rust (all hail the crab) detected. 

i implemented a double buffering system.

idk if this means we should close it or what but thats my experience